# Don't know how to add string to arraylist and make it stick

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm new to java and I was trying to test what I've learned by creating a TestAddRemove program. Essentially it's supposed to make you choose one of two arrays and allows you to add a company name, remove a company name and read whether a company you're looking for is in one of the arrays.

My main problem is with the adding to the arrays part. Each time I add a company using the Add class it works, but then when I check the arrays again the arrays are empty.

**Main Questio**n: How do I add a companyName to an array in the main program and have it stick?

Here's my code:

```
public class TestAddRemove 
{
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static ArrayList<String> fileOne = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> fileTwo = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    :
    :  //Some other stuff
    :
    String tryAgain = "Y";
    String answer;
    String fileAnswer;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the company tester; this program tests whether the company"
            + "you input is a company we already received donations from or a company we have"
            + "spoken to already, but declined to donate."); 

    while (tryAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
    {
        System.out.println("Do you want to test, add or remove a company name? ");
        answer = sc.next();
        String companyName;


        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("add"))
        {
            System.out.println("Which file do you want to add to?");
            fileAnswer = sc.next();

            if (fileAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("fileOne"))
            {
                Add file = new Add(fileOne);
                System.out.println("Enter the company name you want to add. ");
                companyName = sc.next();

                file.addCompany(companyName);
            }
            else
            {
                Add file = new Add(fileTwo);
                System.out.println("Enter the company name you want to add. ");
                companyName = sc.next();

                file.addCompany(companyName);
            }
```

The rest of the code is for the remove and test methods which I think I could understand once I understand how to add the companyName.

Here's the Add Class:

```
public class Add 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> file;

    public Add(ArrayList<String> fileOne)
    {
        this.file = fileOne;
    }

    public void addCompany (String companyName)
    {

        file.add(companyName);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFile()
    {
        return file;
    }

}
```

Any help on this would be awesome, thanks and cheers!

Comment: The provided code seems to work fine. Did you try setting breakpoints and debugging the code? How do you run the application? Data is not persisted between multiple runs.

Comment: It runs fine the first time i run it, all the strings are in the arrays. However when I run the program again, the strings that I previously input into the arrays aren't there.

The application is supposed to store strings in the arrays. And when I run the program again and add more strings to the array, the previously inputted strings and the newly input strings should all be there.

Comment: If you run the program a second time, it's totally unaware of any state set in previous runs. That's where you'd need a persistence layer such as a database. The strings at runtime are only stored in the memory of the current JVM and are discarded when the container shuts down.

Comment: So I'd need to learn about databases. Okay thanks, I'll try to find some website to learn about it.

Do you have any recommendations for website though?

Answer (score 3):

Running a Java application spawns a new JVM container. Such a container has its own memory in which it stores state for your program. When an application terminates, the JVM shuts down and discards all existing state. When you run the program a second time it runs in a different JVM totally unaware of any previous runs.

Regarding your problem, to access the list of companies created in a previous run, you need to add some sort of a persistence layer to your application like a database or a file in which you're able to store the companies.

The simplest solution would be to store the list in a text file, where each line represents one company, before the application shuts down and then load the file again when the application starts.

Comment: Okay, I get it. So it runs the program without regards for any previous runs. Thanks Luciano, appreciate the answer.